# Chrome Developer Tools cannot show <pre> tag in Network->Preview tab

Tags: google-chrome, google-developer-tools

I'm using PHP with Xdebug. Yesterday everything is OK but today I have one problem: My Chrome Developer tools cannot show the HTML which formatted by Xdebug, all lines are combined to one line.

The RAW HTML in `Network->Response` tab is something like this:

```
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<small>C:\wamp\Debug.php:68:</small>
<b>array</b> <i>(size=18)</i>
  'name' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'abc'</font> <i>(length=56)</i>
  'img' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'http://product.net/1000169499.jpg'</font> <i>(length=69)</i>
</pre>
```

I have tested by http://htmledit.squarefree.com/ and it shows normally but in `Network->Preview` displays:

[image]

Respone Headers is `Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8`

I'm using Chrome Version 61.0.3163.79 (Official Build) (64-bit).

How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=763921&can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=) was fixed. Tested on Version 70.0.3538.77 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 2):

I have created a [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=763921&can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=) with the Chrome team

Comment: Great. Let's wait the bug fix

Answer (score 1):

What I've found is that you gonna need `<pre></pre>` between your variable. I've created a snippet to replace 'vardump' with this:

```
foreach ($variable as $key => $reg) {
    echo "<pre>{$key} => '{$reg}'</pre>";
}
var_dump($variable);die;
```

Ps: I'm repeating the data with the last var_dump to get the filename and line

So this:
[image]
Became this:
[image]

Let me know if this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your help. However this issue was fixed on v62.x

Comment: Good to now. Thanks

Comment: Hi, Im In version 62.0.3202.75 and have this problem When I var_dump a variable

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using chrome version 61.0.3163.79 on ubuntu linux.

I switched to chromium browser version 60.0.3112.113 and the xdebug output was fine.

I think that this is a chrome version problem.